# How to test if the object is created correctly while keeping the class under test in isolation?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, tdd, mockito

It is often told that writing unit tests one must test only a single class and mock all the collaborators. I am trying to learn TDD to make my code design better and now I am stuck with a situation where this rule should be broken. Or shouldn't it?

An example: class under test has a method that gets a `Person`, creates an `Employee` based on the `Person` and returns the `Employee`.

```java
public class EmployeeManager {

    private DataMiner dataMiner;

    public Employee getCoolestEmployee() {
        Person dankestPerson = dataMiner.getDankestPerson();
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        employee.setName(dankestPerson.getName() + "bug in my code");
        return employee;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Should `Employee` be considered a collaborator? If not, why not? If yes, how do I properly test that 'Employee' is created correctly?

Here is the test I have in mind (using JUnit and Mockito):

```java
@Test
public void coolestEmployeeShouldHaveDankestPersonsName() {
    when(dataMinerMock.getDankestPerson()).thenReturn(dankPersonMock);
    when(dankPersonMock.getName()).thenReturn("John Doe");

    Employee coolestEmployee = employeeManager.getCoolestEmployee();
    assertEquals("John Doe", coolestEmployee.getName());
}
```

As you see, I have to use `coolestEmployee.getName()` - method of the `Employee` class that is not under Test.

One possible solution that comes to mind is to extract the task of transforming `Person`s into `Employee`s to a new method of `Employee` class, something like

`public Employee createFromPerson(Person person);`

Am I overthinking the problem? What is the correct way?

Comment: I cannot see what is the problem. Your test looks fine. Yes, you are calling `dankPersonMock.getName()` method. But it is fine since it's mock object.

Comment: But I am also calling `coolestEmployee.getName()` and `coolestEmployee` is not a mock. I'll clarify it in the question, too.

Comment: Still, I cannot see any problems here. As for me, the test looks fine.

Comment: So you are saying that `Employee` shouldn't be considered a collaborator  in this case and I am free to use its getters and setters and possibly other methods in the test without breaking any TDD or unit testing principles?

Comment: As I know it's ok. Maybe I'm wrong, but I think, that you even good to use getters, since you encapsulate all the data in your class. You have no access to name field directly, so you shouldn't care what is in field `name` or if there is such field at all. All you should care is that you can get name and that it's correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The goal of a unit test is to quickly and reliably determine whether a single system is broken. That doesn't mean you need to simulate the entire world around it, just that you should ensure that collaborators you use are fast, deterministic, and well-tested.

Data objects—POJOs and generated value objects in particular—tend to be stable and well-tested, with very few dependencies. Like other heavily-stateful objects, they also tend to be very tedious to mock, because mocking frameworks don't tend to have powerful control over state (e.g. `getX` should return `n` after `setX(n)`). Assuming Employee is a data object, it is likely a good candidate for actual use in unit tests, provided that any logic it contains is well-tested.

Other collaborators not to mock in general:

- JRE classes and interfaces. (Never mock a List, for instance. It'll be impossible to read, and your test won't be any better for it.)
- Deterministic third-party classes. (If any classes or methods change to be `final`, your mock will fail; besides, if you're using a stable version of the library, it's no spurious source of failure either.)
- Stateful classes, just because mocks are much better at testing interactions than state. Consider a fake instead, or some other test double.
- Fast and well-tested other classes that have few dependencies. If you have confidence in a system, and there's no hazard to your test's determinism or speed, there's no need to mock it.

**What does that leave?** Non-deterministic or slow service classes or wrappers that you've written, that are stateless or that change very little during your test, and that may have many collaborators of their own. In these cases, it would be hard to write a fast and deterministic test using the actual class, so it makes a lot of sense to use a test double—and it'd be very easy to create one using a mocking framework.

**See also:** Martin Fowler's article ["Mocks Aren't Stubs"](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html), which talks about all sorts of test doubles along with their advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Getters that only read a private field are usually not worth testing. By default, you can rely on them pretty safely in other tests. Therefore I wouldn't worry about using `dankestPerson.getName()` in a test for EmployeeManager.

There's nothing wrong with your test as far as testing goes. The design of the production code might be different - mocking `dankestPerson` probably means that it has an interface or abstract base class, which might be a sign of overengineering especially for a business entity. What I would do instead is just new up a `Person`, set its name to the expected value and set up `dataMinerMock` to return it.

Also, the use of "Manager" in a class name might indicate a lack of cohesion and too broad a range of responsibilities.